# Is a subsheaf indeed a sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading Qing Liu's "*Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*." In the book p. 34, it gives the definition of subsheaf.

> There is a natural notion of *subsheaf $\mathcal F'$ of $\mathcal F$* : $\mathcal F'(U)$ is a subgroup of $\mathcal F(U)$, and the restriction $\rho'_{UV}$ is induced by $\rho_{UV}$.

I see that a subsheaf of a sheaf is a presheaf. But I can't prove that it's a sheaf. I proved the uniqueness condition of sheaf, but I couldn't prove the condition of glueing local sections.

Here's my attempt for proving the glueing local sections condition.
Let $X$ be the given topological space. Let $U$ be an open subset of $X$, $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ a covering of $U$ by open subsets $U_i$. Let $s_i\in\mathcal F'(U_i)$, $i\in I$, be sections such that $s_i|_{U_i\cap U_j} = s_j|_{U_i\cap U_j}$. I should prove that there is $s\in\mathcal F'(U)$ such that $s|U_i = s_i$ for each $i\in I$. Since $\mathcal F$ is a sheaf, there exists a section $s\in\mathcal F(U)$ such that $s|U_i = s_i$. But the problem is that $s$ may not be in $\mathcal F'(U)$.

Comment: That looks like a subpresheaf to me.

Comment: @Lord So even when we assume that $\mathcal F$ is a sheaf, is there $\mathcal F'$ that satisfies the definition in the quote, but is not a sheaf?

Comment: Think of a presheaf $\cal P$, and its sheafification ${\cal P}^+$. There's a map ${\cal P}\to{\cal P}^+$. This is not necessarily an injection, but in many familiar examples it is. So setting ${\cal F}={\cal P}^+$ and ${\cal F}'={\cal P}$ we see that sheaves can have subpresheaves that are not sheaves.

Comment: @Lord Thanks! I'll think about an explicit example.

Comment: To give a concrete example of Lord Shark's comment, you can consider a monomorphism of sheaves $\mathcal{F\to G}$ and consider the quotient presheaf as a subpresheaf of the quotient sheaf. In general, it's not a sheaf

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg But in your answer $\mathcal{C}_b$ is not a subsheaf (maybe I'm still wrong  -to be honest I haven't written down the argument- but your example does not work).

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg : here's a sketch of proof : If$s\in \mathcal{G}(U)$, and  $[s]\in \mathcal{G/F}(U)$ (quotient *pre*sheaf) has $0$ stalks everywhere, it means that for all $x\in U$, there is a nbhd $U_x\subset U$ where $s_{\mid U_x} \in \mathcal{F}(U_x)$. But then, these clearly satisfy the gluing condition, and so lift to a unique $s\in \mathcal{F}(U)$ that lifts them, thus $[s] = 0$

Comment: Dear @Max: you are right that the quotient presheaf injects into the quotient sheaf and I have deleted my previous comment.  However this does not address the question  unless you give an explicit example where that injection is not surjective, in other words an example in which the quotient presheaf is **not** a sheaf.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg : yes, I was actually only providing this as a way to concretize Lord Shark's comment, not as a full answer. If zxcv wants it though, I can definitely provide an example as an answer (if there weren't any examples, sheaf cohomology would be pretty dull, wouldn't it ? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it is not true that that $\mathcal F'$ is necessarily a subsheaf: the definition in your book only defines a separated subPREsheaf of $\mathcal F$.
**Counterexample:**
The sheaf $\mathcal C$ on $\mathbb R$ of continuous real-valued functions has as subpresheaf $\mathcal C_b \subset \mathcal C$ the preshaf of **bounded** continuous functions defined by the requirement that for $U\subset \mathbb R$ open  $$\mathcal C_b(U)=\{f:U\to \mathbb R\vert f \operatorname {is continuous and bounded}\}$$
This is not a sheaf because if we consider the open covering $U_i=(-i,i) (i=1,2,3,\dots)$ of $ \mathbb R$, the functions $f_i\in \mathcal C_b(U_i)$ defined by $f_i(x)=x$ are of course compatibly defined but do not glue to a bounded function in $\mathcal C_b (\mathbb R)$.
Of course they do glue to the continuous (unbounded!) function  $f\in \mathcal C(\mathbb R)$ defined by $f(x)=x$, as they should since $\mathcal C$ **is** a sheaf.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another counterexample, on the discrete space $X=\{a,b\}$. Let $\mathcal F$ be the constant presheaf $U\mapsto\mathbb Z$ if $U\ne\emptyset$ and $\emptyset\mapsto 0$. Here, $\mathcal F$ is *not* a sheaf, since $0\in\mathcal F(\{a\})$ and $1\in\mathcal F(\{b\})$ both restricts to $0\in\mathcal F(\emptyset)=0$, but they are not a common restriction of anything in $\mathcal F(X)=\mathbb Z$.

Then, the sheafification $\widetilde{\mathcal F}$ is given $\emptyset\mapsto 0$, $\{a\},\{b\}\mapsto\mathbb Z$, and $X\mapsto\mathbb Z^2$, with the natural projection as the restriction. We see that $\mathcal F$ is a sub-presheaf of $\widetilde{\mathcal F}$, but is not a sheaf.